# Why is $S=\{U \subseteq \mathbb R:\mathbb R \setminus U \text{ is finite}\}$ a topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a worksheet for my real analysis course that sets up a problem by defining "a new topology $S$ on $\mathbb R$ by declaring a set $U \subseteq \mathbb R$ to be in $S$ if $\mathbb R \setminus U$ is finite." We haven't covered topologies in class yet, but the worksheet says that one of the conditions for a thing $T$ to be a topology is that $\emptyset \in T$.

It seems to me that $\mathbb R \setminus \emptyset$ would not be finite, because it would simply be $\mathbb R$ which is not finite. So $\emptyset \subset S$, but $\emptyset \notin S$. This would mean $S$ is not a topology. Have I misunderstood something about topologies?

Comment: The cofinite topology is defined to contain all cofinite subsets, as well as the empty set.

Comment: You are correct, you have to explicitly add the empty set to $S$ to make it a topology. This is the so-called “co-finite” topology.

Comment: So as literally written, S would not be a topology? If so, is it a convention to implicitly add the empty set as needed when defining a topology?

Comment: Now that I've got a name, it looks like https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1876571/698711 is related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, $\mathbb{R} \setminus \emptyset = \mathbb{R}$ which is not finite. To be a topology the empty set must be included and $S$ doesn't include the empty set. You seem to understand it correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Is it a convention to implicitly add the empty set as needed when defining a topology?

Comment: I would expect the empty set and the entire set to be tacitly included in the topology if they're claiming it is one.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: "tacitly" means the same as "implicitly". Did you mean "explicitly"?

Comment: For something to be explicit, it has to be stated right there for you to read.

Comment: @TonyK I meant tacitly. I'm just ridiculously pedantic and prefer rephrasing thing to avoid repetition. I don't know why I'm this way but I've come to accept it about myself.